# Why the difference in GeometricScenes?

Tags: bugs, geometry

Studying a new `GeometricScene` command, I try

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, d -> {0, 1}, 
e -> {1/2, 1}}, {Rectangle[a, c], Triangle[{a, b, d}]}]
```

which works well (see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vz36shcas6u39e9/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202021-12-07%2016.53.57.png?dl=0)). After that I execute

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, d -> {0, 1}, 
e -> {1/2, 1}}, {Rectangle[a, c], Triangle[{a, e, d}]}]
```

which returns the input instead of a picture without any communication.

What is the reason of these different results?

Comment: Please file a [bug report](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback) about the second input failing.

Comment: @JasonB.: Done. Only thanks, no reply with [CASE ....].

Comment: I reproduce the bug with version 13.1.0 on Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an update from `13.2` - see the screenshot below

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Nice to see it. Works also in 13.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: @user64494 thanks for letting me know. it's good to know that it was version dependent and not OS related!

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what version of Mathematica You are using.

This wrapper for graphical output is needed in mine:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, d -> {0, 1}, 
   e -> {1/2, 1}}, {Rectangle[a, c], Triangle[{a, b, d}]}], 
 RandomSeeding -> 1]
```

[image: graphics output with Randominstance and RandomSeeding]

Comment: Thank you. Works in 13 on Windows 10. Unfortunately, I don't find any description of the  `RandomSeeding -> 1` option in [the documentation to `RandomSeeding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomSeeding.html).

Comment: The `RandomSeeding -> 2` and `RandomSeeding -> 1234` and `RandomSeeding -> Automatic` options also work here.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not it: the question is about `GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, d -> {0, 1}, 
e -> {1/2, 1}}, {Rectangle[a, c], Triangle[{a, e, d}]}]`, not about `GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, d -> {0, 1}, 
e -> {1/2, 1}}, {Rectangle[a, c], Triangle[{a, b, d}]}]`. The command  `RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, d -> {0, 1}, 
   e -> {1/2, 1}}, {Rectangle[a, c], Triangle[{a, e, d}]}], 
 RandomSeeding -> 1]` still returns the input in version 13 on Windows 10.

Comment: `RandomInstance` does nothing in your code, because the `GeometricScene` specification  already contains explicit values for all points.